# In `readr::read_csv()`,When parse "German language",`Ü` become `¨1`, how to solver it

Tags: tidyverse, readr

In `readr::read_csv()`,When parse "German language",`Ü` become `¨1`, how to solver it? Thanks!

readr::read_csv(I("type\nBlitzangebotsgebühr\nÜbertrag"),locale = locale(encoding='ISO-8859-1'))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using UTF8 will fix our problem.

```
library(readr)

read_csv(I("type\nBlitzangebotsgebühr\nÜbertrag"), locale = locale(encoding='utf-8'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks !  Maybe it's my Windows problem, when run your code ,error message ocur "Error: Invalid multibyte sequence"

Comment: Does encoding='latin1' work for you (I don’t have a windows machine so I cant test it)?

Comment: encoding='latin1'  still the same ,but thanks for you kindness

Comment: you can try “Windows 1252” or “ISO-8859-1” as per https://data-se.netlify.app/2019/01/25/reading-text-files-and-umlaute-hassle/

Comment: Thanks for your linkage , maybe it's really my windows problem , it's stil the same.  Just let lay aside currently.